# Backbone: Uncaught ReferenceError: attribute is not defined

Tags: backbone.js

I am using gem 'backbone-on-rails' #https://github.com/meleyal/backbone-on-rails and I am trying to create a "new quote" view, with a blank form. Should be very simple. :S But all I get is this error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: description is not defined** By debugging the error appears to happen on the View->render method.

This is the code:

Router:

```
class SpencerGrafica.Routers.Quotes extends Backbone.Router
    routes:
        'new'       : 'newQuote'

    newQuote: ->
        new SpencerGrafica.Views.NewQuote model: new SpencerGrafica.Models.Quote
```

View:

```
class SpencerGrafica.Views.NewQuote extends Backbone.View
  el: '#app'
  template: JST["quotes/new"]

  initialize: ->
    @render()

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(@model.toJSON()))
    @
```

Model

```
class SpencerGrafica.Models.Quote extends Backbone.Model

  defaults:
    description: null
```

Template

```
<form id="new-quote" name="quote">

  <div>
    <input type="text" name="description" value="<%= description %>" placeholder="Descripcion interna">
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Add Post" />
  </div>

</form>
```

Any help REALLY appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you test your template outside Backbone with a simple JSON object? I can't see any other reason this error would pop up.

Comment: You are passing in `model.toJSON()` to the template, but in the template you are looking for a variable named `description`. It's likely that what you want in the template is actually `model.description`. Try that and see if it works. If that's not the issue make sure that description is something that exists on your model.

Comment: @DigTheDoug: The `@model.toJSON()` should be returning `{description: null}` unless something (such as backbone-on-rails) has changed the default `toJSON` behavior; Rails would want to see `{quote: { description: ... }}` so I'd look at what backbone-on-rails is doing. So I wonder what `console.log(@model.toJSON())` has to say inside `render`.

Comment: By adding `console.log(@model.toJSON())` like this: 
`render: ->
    console.log(@model.toJSON())
    $(@el).html(@template(quote: @model))`
I get this:
`Object {description: null}`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
class SpencerGrafica.Views.NewQuote extends Backbone.View
  el: '#app'
  template: JST["quotes/new"]

  initialize: ->
    @render()

  render: =>  # fat arrow here
    $(@el).html(@template(@model.toJSON()))
```